# Can I replace songs inside a playlist with a position index

Tags: spotify

I would like to know if there is any way to replace songs inside a playlist with a position index, just like the add tracks endpoint. 
When I add "position" to my body parameters I get an error telling me to add "range_start" as if I was calling the reorder endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Replace takes the same parameters for this as Reorder endpoint, although the documentation doesn't state this, the Web Console at [Reorder or replace a Playlist's Tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-playlist-tracks/)  does - I didn't actually know this until I checked that myself, as had assumed only the entire playlist could be replaced

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't seem like it could be of any use here.
I tried to make a call with range_start = 100 and insert_before = 0 but it doesn't seem to do anything on my playlist
I don't know if my call is faulty or if you just cant to be honest

Comment: I'll be interested to see if it actually works as was surprised to see it in the console but haven't tried it myself